# CSS Selector to target specific text within an element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have perhaps quite an odd question and it seems almost to be asking too much of CSS, but if it could be done it would be quite beneficial...

I would like to, rather than using a `<span>` to select individual words be able to use a CSS selector to select a/some specific word(s) within an element, for example a `<div>` or a long `<p>`.

For example (I am aware that this doesn't exist[in ths particuar inflection]):

```
div[text~"hello"] {
     color: red;
}
```

This would find any iteration of the word `hello` in a div, and color it red.

**Pseudocode**
select text equal to "hello" in any div
set colour as red

I would like the equivalent of:

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit <span class="red">hello</span> elit.
```

But I am looking for a CSS specific (and less bulky) way to do this.

Comment: Here are the available pseudo elements, as you can see there currently isn't anything that does what you are looking for 
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-elements